# Is there a need to destroy char * = "string" or char * = new char[6]?

Tags: c++, memory

I assume that `char* = "string"` is the same to `char* = new char[6]`. I believe these strings are created on the heap instead of the stack. So do I need to destroy them or free their memory when I'm done using them or do they get destroyed by themselves?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No. You only need to manually free strings when you manually allocate the memory yourself using the `malloc` function (in C) or the `new` operator (in C++). If you do not use `malloc` or `new`, then the `char*` or string will be created on the stack or as a compile-time constant.

Comment: I think that string literal is allocated in `.rodata` section not in the stack.

Answer (score 18):

No. When you say:

```
const char* c = "Hello World!";
```

You are assigning c to a "pre-existing" string constant which is NOT the same as:

```
char* c = new char[6];
```

Only in the latter case are you allocating memory on the heap. So you'd call delete when you're done.

Answer (score 5):

The name of the game is "destroy only what you created". Here are the pairs:

1. `malloc`/`free`
2. `calloc`/`free`
3. `new`/`delete`
4. `new []`/`delete []`

Since you created the 2nd string using `new []`, the onus is on you to destroy it with `delete []`. Call `delete [] string2` when you are done.

Now if your code is convoluted enough and makes keeping track of deletions difficult, consider the usage of scoped pointers or auto pointers. The [`boost::scoped_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) class from boost library is a good place to begin. Also look into the [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) idiom, pretty handy and useful stuff.

Answer (score 4):

> I assume when I do `char* = "string"` its the same thing as `char* = new char[6]`.

No. What the first one does is create a constant. Modifying it is undefined behaviour. But to answer your question; no, you don't have to destroy them. And just a note, always use `std::string` whenever possible.

Answer (score 3):

They're not the same. Your first example is a constant string, so it's definitely not allocated from the heap. Your second example is a runtime memory allocation of 6 characters, and that comes from the heap. You don't want to delete your first example, but you need to `delete []` your second example.

Comment: "new" allocates memory from the heap, never from the stack. (Unless, of course, you have overridden the new operator.)

Comment: My bad. I knew that. Really. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't know where the string literals are stored. It may even be read-only memory, so your code should read:

```
const char* c = "string";
```

And a *new* char array should be *delete*d just like any other dynamically allocated memory area.

Answer (score 1):

**Let's see what GCC 4.8 x86-64 Linux does**

Program:

```
#include <cstdio>
int main() {
    const char *s = "abc";
    char *sn = new char[4];
    sn[3] = '\0';
    std::printf("%s\n", s);
    std::printf("%s\n", sn);
}
```

Compile and decompile:

```
g++ -c -ggdb -o a.o -std=c++98 a.cpp
objdump -CSr a.o
```

The output contains:

```
  const char *s = "abc";
 8:   48 c7 45 f0 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,-0x10(%rbp)
 f:   00 
                     c: R_X86_64_32S .rodata
  char *sn = new char[4];
10:   bf 04 00 00 00          mov    $0x4,%edi
15:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  1a <main+0x1a>
                        16: R_X86_64_PC32       operator new[](unsigned long)-0x4
1a:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
```

Interpretation:

- `char *s = "abc"` goes into `.rodata`. So you cannot `free` it in any way.
- `char *sn = new char[4];` comes from the output of `operator new[]`. So you should free it when you can.

Comment: I think you should add `-c` flag in `g++ -ggdb -std=c++98 a.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

new is always an allocation whereas defining a string inline actually embeds the data in the program itself and cannot be changed (some compilers allow this by a smart trick, don't bother).

Some compilers type inline strings so that you cannot modify the buffer.

```
char* const sz1 = "string"; // embedded string, immutable buffer
char* sz2 = new char[10]; // allocated string, should be deleted
```