# Converting string from lowercase to uppercase seg fault

Tags: c

I am trying to convert a string that has been passed to this function from lowercase to uppercase. I keep getting a seg fault, and cannot determine why.

```
void uppercase(char* input)
{
    int str_size = strlen(input);
    char *string = input;
    for (int i = 0; i < str_size; i++)
    {
      string[i] += -32;
      printf("%c", string[i]);
    }
    return;
}
```

Function calling the function uppercase:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{

  uppercase("max");

  return(0);

}
```

Comment: I'm nearly certain that you are calling this function with a pointer pointing to a string literal.

Comment: I think you should also show the code where this function is called. This function looks fine, the problem probably lies where this function is called.

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve], which includes the `main` function and `#include`s.

Comment: Yup as dasblinkenlight said, you cannot modify a string literal because the literal is placed in *read* *only* *memory*!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dasblinkenlight said, you [cannot modify a string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51607/3823831).

Try this instead:

```
int main(void)
{
  char str[4] = "max";
  uppercase(str);

  return(0);
}
```

Or you can also malloc a string and pass it in.

Comment: Or `(char[]){"max"}`

Answer (score 1):

The string that you are passing is a literal possibly present in read-only memory (since it is a string literal which is a constant) which you aren't allowed to modify. Hence the error.

Store the string in a character array and then pass that to the function.

```
char str[]="max";
uppercase(max);
```

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/storage-for-strings-in-c/

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/294748/why-are-c-string-literals-read-only

Comment: @Jas You're right. Added.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass string literals as an argument to the function. try storing it first in array and then pass it to the function.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  void uppercase(char* input)
  {
  int str_size = strlen(input);
  char *string = input;
  for (int i = 0; i < str_size; i++)
  {
  string[i] += -32;
  printf("%c", string[i]);
  }
  return;
  }

  int main(void)
  {
  char str[]="max";
  uppercase(str);
  return(0);
  }
```